# IIS is trying to access the wrong web.config

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis

So first a bit of background: I rechecked out my SVN repository to a new location and tried to run the application from there. And now Visual Studio is having problems launching my MVC application using Local IIS Web server.
I am currently getting this error:

> The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
>
> Detailed Error Information:
> Module     IIS Web Core
> Notification       Unknown
> Handler    Not yet determined
> Error Code     0x80070003
> Config Error       Cannot read configuration file
> Config File    \?\C:\RND\app\web.config
> Requested URL      https: //localhost:44304/app
> Physical Path
> Logon Method       Not yet determined
> Logon User     Not yet determined
> Request Tracing Dir

And the problem is that the config file does not exist at c:\RND\app\web.config it is now located at c:\RND\appTest\web.config.

Is there a way I can update this in Visual Studio?

It is as if it has saved the old path somewhere and not automatically updating it.

Comment: You might want to check your system path to see if the path was added there. I would also recommend closing out of your environment and reloading it in case you have a cached copy saved.

Answer (score 16):

You can correct this behavior by simply deleting the .vs file located in your project, and rebuilding the project. Visual Studio will regenerate another .vs file with the path to the web.config corrected. There are stored the settings about the web.config file path, among the others.

Comment: Didn't even had to delete the folder, just updating the .config file worked!

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue after moving my project folder. I fixed it by editing the IISExpress applicationhost.config file and correcting the faulty paths found in it.

On my machine the applicationhost.config file was found in C:\Users\\Documents\IISExpress\config

Answer (score 2):

I fix it by removing a file named "applicationhost.config" stored in the .vs folder at the same level of .sln file.
This file contains all the info about solution, by deleting it visual studio needs to recreate it with the default value.